# preserv leading zeros fetched in SQL at excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel-2010

i have SQL query which fetches item details from table, this SQL include lot number as a field, i have noticed that when i run the query few rows have either leading zeros or text look like 51E03 when i export to excel, leading zeros will go off 00021 became 21 and 51E03 will converted 51000, is it possible to retain the values as is when it get copy with headers from SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve leading zeros by prepending the numeric values with a single quote.  Well, actually, if they have leading zeros, then they are really character strings.  So, something like this:

```
select '''' + AccountNumber
from table t;
```